# How can I validate a sentence using PHP and JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

I am currently trying to validate if the sentence a user enters matches the expected sentence. The expected sentence is stored in a PHP variable `$rebuiltSentence`, for example 'the cat sat'.

The problem is that when I try to call my JavaScript function `formSubmit()` I need to give it the sentence to check, therefore ideally I would call formSubmit($rebuiltSentence). I think this won't work because it thinks it is being passed several separate strings.

Here is what I've got:

```
//sentence.php

<input type='button' value='Submit' onClick=formSubmit('$rebuiltSentence')
```

and

```
//validate.js
function formSubmit(correct)
{
var contents = document.getElementById('sentenceBuilder').value;
if(contents==correct){

    alert('The Sentences Match');
}else{
    alert('The Sentences Dont Match');
}

window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should quote the attribute and escape it properly:

```
echo '<... onClick="formSubmit(' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($rebuiltSentence)) . ');">'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the sentence as a hidden field to validate against.

```
//sentence.php

<input type='hidden' id=rebuiltSentence value='$rebuildSentence'>
<input type='button' value='Submit' onClick=formSubmit()>
```

and to validate you could then easily use

```
//validate.js
function formSubmit()
{
  var contents = document.getElementById('sentenceBuilder').value;
  var correct  = document.getElementById('rebuiltSentence').value;
  if(contents==correct)
  {
    alert('The Sentences Match');
  }else{
    alert('The Sentences Dont Match');
  }

  window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the string $rebuiltSentence rather than the sentence that this parameter holds in PHP.

Change to the follwoing

//sentence.php

```
echo "<input type='button' value='Submit' onClick=formSubmit('".$rebuiltSentence."')";
```

and it will echo the content of $rebuiltSentence.

Comment: This won't work if $rebuiltSentence contains a single quote, and won't be right if it contains, e.g. an ampersand.